# Только Google, Facebook и другие крупные сервисы могут генерировать 3rd party cookies или другие обычные сайты тоже могут?

Tags: google-chrome, cookie, facebook

Я знаю что такие рекламные сервисы как Google , Facebook  и тд.  из разных сайтов посредством 3-rd party Cookies собирают все о нас и все наши действие и таким образом формируют  наш пользовательский профиль.

Вопрос  В том что только такие компании как Google, Facebook  и тд. могут собирать всю эту информацию? или обычные сайты тоже могут так делать или получить доступ к этой информации ?
например если я зашла какой то  сайт и там рекламируются другие сайты. эти сайты (которые рекламируются ) могут отправить мне свои собственные файлы Cookie  и получить информацию о моих действиях в сайте или в просторе интернет?

Answer (score 0):

3rd part cookies это куки которые ставит не сайт, который вы посещаете, а другой сайт, виджет которого есть на это сайте. Например, яндекс-метрика, кнопка фейсбука или ВК, гугл-аналитика, и т.д. Если на сайте, которой вы посещаете, нет соответствующего кода (который туда добавляет владелец сайта, а не гугл или фейсбук), то и куки гугл или фейсбук поставить не может.

Т.е. любая фирма может собирать информацию с какого-нибудь сайта, условие: владелец сайта добавил код на свой сайт и пользователь не запретил куки третьей стороны.

Технически сайт не должен иметь возможности читать чужие куки. Исключения: думаю, что производители браузеров могут читать любые куки (привет, гугель хром).

Comment: да я знаю что 3rd party cookies создают сторонние сайты .
мой вопрос был другой . например с помощью Google рекламы рекламодатель размещает свою рекламу на X сайте. 
заходя в этот сайт  мой браузер получает Cookies от Google или от сайта рекламодателя ?в таком случае рекламодатель может получить информацию о моих дейсвиях в интернете ?

Comment: это уже вопрос реализации рекламы. Может и от гугла, может и от рекламодателя. Ну т.е. от гугла-то в любом случае, где это видано, чтобы гугл не оставил куку, если есть такая возможность.

Comment: ясное дело что Google оставит Cookie. но если я не взаимодействовал с рекламой рекламодателя как рекламодатель может получить информацию о моих действиях ? разве что он может получить информацию лишь через сервисы Google не так ли ? разве 3rd party cookies могут поставить только не те сайты чьи API интегрирован в данном сайте ?